# Can anyone please tell me how can we use our local JSON data in DropDown Menu in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to fetch my local JSON data in Dropdown Menu but it is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you local data is stored in the assets then

1. You have to make sure it's declared in the pubscpec.yaml
2. Use the path defined in the pubspec.yaml and do the following to get the data

   ```
   var jsonString =
       await rootBundle.loadString('assets/localJson/ourLocalJson.json');
   var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
   ```

to import the json.decode method import the dart:convert package.